# Understanding Jenkinsfile Syntax (Build Job)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have no experience in writing Jenkinsfiles yet and want to learn the syntax now. In more detail it is about triggering a job with parameters in a scripted pipeline. I have looked at the following documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/. 
As I understand it, a jobname and optionally an array of parameter objects (e.g. the object "string" or "booleanParam" etc.) must be passed. So the following call should work.:

```
build job: "${env.JOB_NAME}", parameters: [string(name: 'Nodes', value: "10")]
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: lag for class: groovy.lang.Binding
Possible solutions: class
```

I guess I don't really understand the documentation and the types used with it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post the complete script as it looks like the error is pointing to a piece of code that you have not posted

Comment: The `build job:` directive is used when you want to trigger another job from the current pipeline job. In your example, `"${env.JOB_NAME}"` refers to the current job, which is not the correct usage. If you want to set up build parameters for the current job, see this basic example https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines.